# Renaming file in Angular CLI build script

Tags: angular-cli, npm-scripts

Assuming that I needed to rename `index.html` to `abc.xyz` during the `ng build` process, is that possible?  If so, how would I go about doing it?

I am assuming that I would have to modify the `package.json` `build` script, and probably use pipes, but I haven't been able to figure it out by looking at either the Angular CLI github or via NPM's site.  Google hasn't helped me either...I must not be asking it the right questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing like that in `CLI` that you can rename the files, however you can do that just by using a custom npm script. There is a multiple options how you can do that:

- If you are on `Windows` you can use `move` cmd command within your npm `build script`:

  ```json
  "build": "ng build && move dist\\index.html dist\\abc.xyz"
  ```
- If you are on `Linux` you have to use `mv` instead:

  ```json
  "build": "ng build && mv dist/index.html dist/abc.xyz"
  ```

Then by running `npm run build` you'll achieve the result you are looking for.

Also you can use [cash-mv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cash-mv) npm package if you want, this way your `build script` will be sort of `cross platform` (Linux version of a script will be valid for all platforms).